# Determining the sign of an expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-distributions

Given a random variable $X$ with continuous density $f$, $\int X f(X)\mathrm{d}X = 0$ and $\int X^2 f(X) \mathrm{d}X = 1$, and a function $h = h(X)$ with $0 < h(X)$, show if the sign of the following expression can be determined:
\begin{equation}
w \equiv \int X h(X)f(X)\mathrm{d}X 
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you have a specific question regarding the prove? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Take $\ X\ $ to be a standard normal variate (density $\ f\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ $) and consider a function $\ h\left(x\right)\ $ of the form
$$
h\left(x\right) = \cases{a& for $\ x<0\ $\\
          b & for $\ 0\le x\ $.}
$$
What is the sign of $\ \int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty x\, h\left(x\right)f\left(x\right) dx \ $ in this case, when $\ 0<a<b\ $?  What about when $\ 0<b<a\ $.

Comment: Given the specification of $h$, we have:                  
\begin{align}
    w &= \int_{-\infty}^0 a X f(X) dX + \int_0^{\infty} b X f(X) dX \\
      &= -a \int_0^{\infty} X f(X) dX + b \int_0^{\infty} X f(X) dX \\
      &= (b-a) \left(\int_0^{\infty} X f(X) dX  \right)
\end{align}                  
Therefore, if $b \geq a$, then $w \geq 0$, otherwise, $w<0$.

Comment: In general, $h$ depends on $X$. Is it possible to sign $w$ based on the sign of $\frac{\partial h(X)}{\partial X}$?